# Consume data from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I am trying to consume the messages from Kafka Topic by specifying the class for below three properties:

```
--property key.deserializer = org.apache.kakfa.common.serialization.StringDesrializer 
--property value.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDesrializer
```

but I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter.init(ConsoleConsumer.scala:477)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:312)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:51)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your class names have a typo (they say `StringDesrializer` and `LongDesrializer`) and one of the package names had `kakfa` instead of `kafka`.

The parameters below should fix your problem:

```
--property key.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer 
--property value.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
```

Comment: Also `kakfa` should be replaced by `kafka`

Comment: Thanks for answering the  question, but even after editing the command got error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter.init(ConsoleConsumer.scala:477)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsoleConsumer.scala:312)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:51)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)

Comment: @mjuarez  please suggest?